# Mac OS, is DVD drive under Sandbox

Tags: macos, sandbox, dvd

Does the DVD drive on MAC OS come under "Sandbox"
If i have a Start.app that opens a HTML file on a DVD, will the user be able to launch the Start.app from DVD directly? Will it work?

Answer (score 0):

DVD Drive does not come under sandbox.
I wrote a DVD and launched the app from DVD drive and it would run successfully.